# What to do get rid of this error in Ubuntu?

Tags: tcl, ns2

```
set tracefile [open out.tr w]
$ns trace-all $namfile
```

When I am running the above TCL code this is showing in terminal. I have just started learning TCL so don't know what to do anything this error.

```
can't read "namfile": no such variable
    while executing
"$ns trace-all $namfile"
```

Comment: Looks like "Net simulator **ns2** otcl commands".  `set tracefile [open out.tr w]` and `$ns trace-all $namfile` are two different lines, and are about two different trace file types. See the example `ex1-Rx.tcl` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PHAMygJidHPppjuzuaRtn5Zbq5dq1nZV?usp=sharing ..... to be run with the **ns** interpreter : `$ ns ex1-Rx.tcl` ........... All 3000 ns2 simulation examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?resourcekey=0-vrEMHtGTFP3yLoTQz_UAwA&usp=sharing

Comment: The provided snippet doesn't set the namfile variable. Do that to "get rid of the error", e.g. `set namfile mynamfile.txt`. What to set it to depends on where the code is from and what it is trying to do, neither of which you provided in the question so far.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: the variable called `namfile` is not set at the point when the code `$ns trace-all $namfile` is run. I can't tell why from the snippet you provided; *maybe* it's because you should have used `$tracefile` instead, or maybe you should set `namfile` to something and haven't done so? Or even possibly something more complicated. (I also don't know whether you're supposed to give a channel or a filename to the `trace-all` method; you should look that up.)